# MS access database searching by field (number)

Tags: forms, ms-access, search

I have a form with a list box which contains operators `<,>,=,` etc (cboOperator is the name for this), and another field for entering the number (Diameter is the name of field). Table using here as one of the field named `S_diameter`, I am trying to do search form using the query form, the query has the fields for data  I wanted to get rows from table based on what user selects the operator and enter a number in to cboOperator and Diameter respectively. I have other fields in the form which is working as per search goes.

Here is that field with criteria in query (design mode).

```
IIf([Forms]![Search Form]![cboOperator] Is Null Or [Forms]![Search Form]![Diameter] Is Null,True,[S_diameter] & [Forms]![Search Form]![cboOperator] & [Forms]![Search Form]![Diameter])
```